# Could not get spell name in WOW addon

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Trying to get name of a spell as it seems like

```
local spellName = select(1, CombatLogGetCurrentEventInfo())
```

returns something like numbers instead plain text like 158989565.009

I was trying to get spell name by function GetSpellInfo(i) but no luck 
Here is code sample that doesn't work:

```
local frame = CreateFrame("FRAME");
frame:RegisterEvent("COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED");

frame:SetScript("OnEvent", function(self, event)
    local type = select(1, CombatLogGetCurrentEventInfo())

    if (type == "SPELL_DAMAGE") then

        local spellId = select(1, CombatLogGetCurrentEventInfo())
        local name = GetSpellInfo(spellId)

        SendChatMessage(name, "SAY", "COMMON", GetUnitName("PLAYERTARGET"));
    end
end)
```

Comment: Try printing the variables `type` and `spellId` and see what's in there. A spell id can't be a decimal, so I'm curious where it comes from. `GetSpellInfo()` with a valid id (not the spell name) returns all you need, so that's no issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but see https://wow.gamepedia.com/COMBAT_LOG_EVENT

```lua
local playerGUID = UnitGUID("player")
local MSG_SPELL_DAMAGE = "Damaged %s with %s"

local frame = CreateFrame("Frame");
frame:RegisterEvent("COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED")
frame:SetScript("OnEvent", function(self, event)
    local timestamp, subevent, _, sourceGUID, sourceName, sourceFlags, sourceRaidFlags, destGUID, destName, destFlags, destRaidFlags, spellId, spellName, spellSchool = CombatLogGetCurrentEventInfo()

    if subevent == "SPELL_DAMAGE" and sourceGUID == playerGUID then
        print(MSG_SPELL_DAMAGE:format(destName, spellName))
    end
end)
```

[Example message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvJRU.png)